# grails schema-export fails with NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

When I launch the Grails command 'grails test schema-export' it fails with the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method containsBean() on null object
```

this is my datasource definition:

```
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        pooled = true
        jmxExport = true
        driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
        username = "sa"
        password = ""
    }
}
```

And the Hibernate closure:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    singleSession = true
    flush.mode = 'manual'
    show_sql = true
}
```

When I run unit tests all work perfectly, so I imagine this is not a GORM model issue.

Stack trace detail:

```
Problem executing: test schema-export stdout
Command terminated with an exception: java.lang.Exception (see details for partial output)
Command: GrailsCommand(P/LEARNGRAILS> test schema-export)
---- System.out ----
.
|Environment set to test
......................................
..Error 
|
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method containsBean() on null object
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
......
------System.err:-----------
Loading Grails 2.4.4
```

Update: 
It fails also with 'test dbm-generate-gorm-changelog changelog.groovy' and the migration plugin. Maybe is something with the project?

Partially resolved by removing the searchable plugin, see my comment below.
'Partially', because I still don't know exactly what's going on.

Comment: Unit tests don't use a database (only a ConcurrentHashMap), so that's not relevant to this issue.

Comment: So the problem is the --compile ":searchable:0.6.9"-- plugin. If I remove it the ddl is generated correctly. But I don't know why..

Comment: I changed hibernate version, downgrading to '3.6.10.18' because I read here on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317599/grails-2-4-hibernate-4-searchable-plugin-classnotfoundexception-org-hiber) that the searchable plugin is not working with hibernate 4, but nothing changed...